# Report Generation inconsistant in protractor

Tags: angularjs, node.js

Im trying to run few simple tests in protractor , and trying to generate XML reports for the same .

```
My conf file :

    // An example configuration file.
    exports.config = {
      directConnect: true,

      // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
      capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
      },
    //multiCapabilities: [{
    //    browserName: 'firefox'
     // }, {
       // browserName: 'chrome'
      //}],
      // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directly when
      // protractor is called.
      specs: ['DriverScript.js'],

       onPrepare: function() {
    // The require statement must be down here, since jasmine-reporters
    // needs jasmine to be in the global and protractor does not guarantee
    // this until inside the onPrepare function.
    browser.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40000);
    browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20000);
    require('jasmine-reporters');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
    new jasmine.JUnitXmlReporter('xmloutput', true, true));
    },

      // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
      jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 10000000
      }
    };
```

Spec File:

```
Spec file : DriverScript

var util = require('util');

describe('Bugzilla', function () {

    beforeEach(function () {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.get('https://landfill.bugzilla.org/bugzilla-4.4-branch/index.cgi/bugzilla/');
    });

    var login = require('../Bugzilla/Login-pom.js');
    it('Login page should be open', function () {

        login.click_login();
        browser.driver.sleep(10000);
        login.userName();
        login.password();
        login.submit();
    });

        var bug = require('../Bugzilla/FileBug-pom.js');
    it('File a Bug page should be open', function () {
        bug.click_fileBug();
        browser.driver.sleep(10000);
        bug.widget();
        browser.driver.sleep(10000);
        bug.severity();
        bug.hardware();
        bug.os();
        bug.description();

    });


});

describe('Bugzilla', function () {



    var search = require('../Bugzilla/search-pom.js');
    it('Search page should be open', function () {

        search.click_home();
        browser.driver.sleep(10000);
        search.click_search();
        browser.driver.sleep(10000);
        search.status();
        search.product();
        search.words();
        search.submit();
        browser.driver.sleep(10000);
    });

});
```

Report is getting generated only for the recently executed test case , or recently failed test case .

I want the report to be generated for all the test cases .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug, but the way JUnitXmlReporter works. It will save each `describe` in a separate file, using the prepend string "xmloutput" and name of your describe as the file name. However, both of your describes are named "Bugzilla", so one will overwrite the other. Simple renaming one of your describes to something else (or put them in the same describe) will fix your issue.

Try to run against something like:

```
describe('working test', function(){

  it('should work 1', function() {
    expect(true).toEqual(true);
  });

  it('should work 2', function() {
    expect(true).toEqual(true);
  });
});

describe('broken test', function(){
  it('should fail 1', function() {
    expect(true).toEqual(false);
  });

  it('should fail 2', function() {
    expect(true).toEqual(false);
  });
});
```

it will generate two files: "xmloutputTEST-brokentest.xml" and "xmloutputTEST-workingtest.xml"